# Trouble sending a POST with Java

Tags: java, http, post

I've read through the other excellent stack overflow articles and tried a lot of them and variations on them but must be making some basic error time and time again? The page I'm posting to works but when I run my java program I just get an empty set on the mySQL database that the data is being posted to. The direct URL that works would be:

```
http://myURL.co.uk/enteremail.php?email=value
```

the code

```
        String data = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode("value1", "UTF-8");         

        URL url = new URL("http://myURL.co.uk/enteremail.php");
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        conn.setDoOutput(true);
        OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(conn.getOutputStream());
        wr.write(data);
        wr.flush();         
        wr.close();
```

I know that there are much better ways of doing this using java but I have to use this way as its a bit of a workaround for another problem.

TIA

Comment: Have you tried to close the output stream before creating the BufferedReader & InputStreamReader?

Comment: I'm not actually expecting any response, its just one of the examples posted here on Stack Overflow that includes it. I'll edit it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd still like to know what was up with my original code, but because what I wanted to do was so simple I've just cut a corner and done this which works for sending the post request to a php page but may not be the solution for anything else:

```
        String email = "myEmail";
        URL post= new URL("http://myURL.co.uk/enteremail.php?email="+email);
        URLConnection goPost = post.openConnection();
        new InputStreamReader(goPost.getInputStream());
```

Hopefully of some help to someone else down the line, [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to close the URL connection as well.

I'd suggest checking out the Apache Http client which will do all the heavy lifting for you.

Comment: I've used that before, its much easier, but I can't use it this time for other reasons - see last line of my question. I've closed the URLconnection and still no joy, just an empty result on the DB?

Comment: Did you try the examples available at http://exampledepot.com/egs/java.net/Post.html ?

Comment: I did yes, I'm not 100% sure it isn't a problem with my web hosting not taking the input in that format. But I'm just guessing.